# datatable tableTools mDataProp not render column if using fnRender

Tags: jquery, datatables, render, tabletools

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/ref) and the [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) add-on.  I want to use [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) with a blank column to export a pdf version of the table. Using [fnRender](http://datatables.net/ref#fnRender)

```
$('#example').dataTable({ 
  'mDataProp':null, 
  'sTitle':'Date',
  'fnRender':function (oObj) {
       return oObj.aData.date.substring(0, 10);
   }
});
```

without [fnRender](http://datatables.net/ref#fnRender) , TableTools works well (of course)

sugestões?

Comment: Are you trying to use a click event on a column to trigger one of the export options provided with TableTools, pdf for example?

Comment: correct, I'm wanting to generate a PDF and the cell is empty

Comment: fnRender is slated to be removed in the next release http://datatables.net/ref#fnRender, and the documents suggest using mRender http://datatables.net/ref#mRender

Comment: i changed to mRender and solved the problem... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fnRender](http://datatables.net/ref#fnRender) is slated to be removed in the next release , and the documents suggest using [mRender](http://datatables.net/ref#mRender).

Answer (score 1):

yes fnRender is no more available in the jquery datatable, Replace **fnRender** with **mRnder**
please also check index of date field by debugg as well, I am going to set oObj.aData[0], but it may be 1,2 etc.

```
    $('#example').dataTable({ 
    'mDataProp':null, 
    'sTitle':'Date',
    'mRender':function (data, type,oObj) {
        return oObj[0].substring(0, 10);
    }
    });
```